# set up passwordless rsync with Strato Hidrive

Tags: rsync

I want to set up a passwordless rsync with my strato hidrive. But I have 2 issues.

First issue is that my id_rsa.pub already exists because of git. Is that an issue?

Secondly I can't seem to run ssh-copy-id to my strato hidrive. This is the command i'm running:
`ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub exo-l@rsync.hidrive.strato.com`

It then returns:
`shell access not allowed`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently strato has an upload form for the SSH key under
Options->Account Manager->OpenSSH Key

I uploaded my key there

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Hidrive but the standard Strato webspace, but I think it is related, as I also get `shell access not allowed` when trying to use `ssh-copy-id`. Following [this blog](http://www.jan-grosser.de/art/342_ssh_zugriff_auf_strato_webspac.html) (German), the following seems to work:

- log into the server with ssh
- create directory `.ssh`
- use scp to copy `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the file `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If you use multiple (s)ftp accounts with different root directories, the procedure can be repeated by creating the `.ssh` directory in the respective root directory of the ftp account. (However you don't have a shell in those auxiliary ftp access points, so `sftp` works but `rsync` not).